# How to find geodesics of hyperbolic plane.

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geodesic

I have the metric $$ds^2=\frac{1}{y^2}(dx^2+dy^2)$$ and I want to find the geodesics. I know this is the metric of the hyperbolic plane which has geodesics $$\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2=y^2$$ and $$\dot{x}=ky^2$$, for some constant $k$ and parameterized with $s$,

but when I use the formula for the geodesics, namely $$(g_{kc} \dot{x}^k)^{\cdot}=\frac{1}{2}g_{ab,c} \dot{x}^a \dot{x}^b$$ where $g_{ab,c}=\frac{ \partial g_{ab}}{\partial x^c}$, $x^1=x$, $x^2=y$ and the dot is differentiation with respect to $s$.

For $c=1$ I get $$\dot{x}=ky^2$$
but for $c=2$ I get something completely different, $$\ddot{y}y=-\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2$$ if I got the calculations right.
So I get different geodesic equations than the ones expected.
Now I understand how  $$\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2=y^2$$ is derived, I can get this by simply dividing the metric with $ds^2$ but my question is, why do I get different geodesic equations using the formula?

Comment: Why $\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2 = 1$? That doesn't seem right. I think you want $\frac{\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2}{y^2} = 1$ (for a unit geodesic)

Comment: Yes you are right, it was a typo, i will fix it

Comment: I don't understand how you get $\dot{x} = ky^2$. Why is there no $\ddot{x}$? What the hell is $k$?

Comment: $k$ is some constant I get by solving $\frac{d}{ds} \left(\frac{\dot{x}}{y^2} \right)=0$ which arises from the formula I mentioned or the Euler-Lagrange equations.

Comment: I agree that $\dot x = ky^2$. The other equation should be $y\ddot y + \dot x^2 - \dot y^2 = 0$.

Comment: Maybe i mess up the calculations for the second equation, but still why is it different than $\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2=y^2$

Comment: I have no idea where you're getting that equation. From the correct one I gave you, you can solve an ODE to see that you get semicircles for the geodesics.

Comment: That equation, by the way, is just saying you have a unit-speed curve. What you really want to do is eliminate $t$ altogether to see the curves in the $xy$-plane.

Comment: If I solve the solve the system $\dot{x}=ky^2$, $\ddot{y}y=-\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2$ will I get the same solutions as the system $\dot{x}=ky^2$,$\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2=y^2$ or the system $\ddot{y}y=-\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2$, $\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2=y^2$?